# What package can plot/analyze fitting result of optim() function easily?

Tags: r, optimization, plot, linear-regression

I am trying to analyze the result of linear regression using lm() and optim().

Actually, the result from lm() function is very easy to plot or analyze by related functions,such as:

```
fit <- lm(y~x1+x2, data=dat)

# I can plot 'Fitted values', 'Theoretical Quantiles', 'Fitted values' and 'Leverage' by plot() easily.

plot(fit)
durbinWatsonTest(fit)
```

But the result from optim() could not be accepted by plot() or other functions, such as:

```
  > result.opt <- optim(par = c(0, 0, 0, 0,0, 0, 0),
                                      min.OLS, 
                                      data = dat 
                       )

> result.opt
$par
[1]  811.06933  285.10077 -476.69048  144.11307  273.46945  -30.65947 -279.02271

$value
[1] 152364.6

$counts
function gradient 
     502       NA 

$convergence
[1] 1

$message
NULL

> plot(result.opt)
Error in xy.coords(x, y, xlabel, ylabel, log) : 
  'x' is a list, but does not have components 'x' and 'y'
```

What package or method can do result analysis as plotting lm's result?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I doubt there is one; `optim()` is a general purpose optimization tool. You could pass it just about anything to optimise and it would give it a go, but how would a package writer know that what you did with `optim()` is an OLS fit but the what some other Joe did with `optim()` was a GLMM fit for example? What works for one type of fit is unlikely to work for another. You'll just have to work on this yourself, perhaps by wrapping the `optim()` call in something else that generates the extra information needed for such plots.

Comment: Hi Gavin, thanks for your input. Your concern makes sense. optim() is a general tool and they don't know what method user provide so that it can not give specific plot. Can we cast the return result from optim() to lm() by some methods so I can apply the routines of OLS ?

Comment: You may want to check `stats4::mle`: it is just a wrapper around `optim`, but it adds all the information you may find interesting when fitting a model via maximum likelihood -- and there is also a `plot` method.

Comment: I don't think there is a `plot.mle` function.  `bbmle::mle2` has slightly more functionality, although maybe not what you're looking for.

Comment: I was referring to the `plot` method for `profile.mle` objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're asking for is a **plot method** for `optim` , but I believe `optim` returns a list with no specific class, so it's not possible to assign it a method. You can easily enough write a small function which grabs the `par` element of the output list and uses that to generate data to plot.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. Yes, I realize that my request doesn't fit the  programming model of OOP so that I have to define my own methods for optim().